# Type error: 'int' object is not calleble

Tags: python, type

Buen día, estoy haciendo un ejercicio no entiendo por que me da este error, creo que el error esta en la clase, pero no doy con el chiste, apenas aprendí a crear clases quizás sea falta de manejo bien de este concepto, como se ve el ejercicio solo me saca un promedio.

```
import math
class Media_Muestral():
     def __init__ (self, Datos={}):
         self.Datos = Datos
         self.LenDatos = len(self.Datos)
         self.X = 0.0
         self.U = 0.0        

     def m_muestra(self):
         for i in self.Datos:
             self.X = i + self.X
             self.U = self.X / self.LenDatos
         print("La media muestral es ",self.U," de los datos ingresados")

datos = {12.6,12.9,13.4,12.3,13.6,13.5,12.6,13.1}
m_muestral = Media_Muestral(datos)
m_muestral.LenDatos()
```

Answer (score 3):

`LenDatos` es una variable entera, no una función.

Para usarla, solo necesitas escribir el nombre del objeto y de la variable, asi:

```
largo = m_muestra1.LenDatos
```